# scale down image size with specified ratio - android

Tags: android, android-studio, image-processing

I wanna to develop a compressed size for images by factors.

after I googled it, I found I can use `compress` function in bitmap as following

```
myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressRatio, out);
```

possible values for **`compressRatio`** is 100, 50 and 25

so that in case of 100 the saved image in original size says (1MB) in case of 50 save size 0.5MB and 25 save in 0.25MB image size.

but actual after I pass the values I get different values for example

> for 100 the size is about 1.4M, for 50 sizes is about 250k, for 25
>   sizes is about 150k, the right scaling should be if for 100 the size
>   is about 1.4M, for 50 sizes is about 700k, for 25 sizes is about 300K

can anyone help me to understand why it not work as expected?

==========================================================

**Edit 1**: 
 as **CommonsWare** mentioned this can't be achieved by `compress()` so is there any suggestion to make what I need real

Hint: I don't want change its width and height I need to keep them as original image dimensions but in different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

> scale down image size with specified ratio - android

This has nothing to do with the `compress()` method on `Bitmap`. Given an existing `Bitmap`, you can [call `createScaledBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) to create a scaled bitmap.

> so that in case of 100 the saved image in original size says (1MB) in case of 50 save size 0.5MB and 25 save in 0.25MB image size.

That is not how the compression factor parameter to `compress()` works. The exact meaning of that value depends on the image format. For JPEG, it controls how lossy the compression can be, but it is not a linear scale. For example, a value of 0 does not allow you to save an image as a zero-byte file.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. is there any way to achieve what I need?
the `createScaledBitmap()` I think will change its width and height I need to keep them as original image dimensions but in different sizes.

can this be achieved?

Comment: @M_ELsaghier: "I need to keep them as original image dimensions but in different sizes" -- I do not know what you mean by this. The dimension *is* the image size. If by "size" you are referring to size in bytes on disk, you cannot change this arbitrarily, and you cannot change it without affecting the quality of the image. As you saw, you can get a smaller file by using a lower compression factor, but the resulting image may not look very good.

Comment: that is what I need to do, change the quality of image but in right way to get what mentioned values.

Comment: @M_ELsaghier: You have no way of knowing how big the file will be until you write the file. Beyond changing the compression factor that you provide to `compress()`, all that you can do is change the colors in the image. For example, a solid black image will compress better than will a photo of a flower, even if both images have the same resolution.

Comment: you mean I can't achieve what I need just try to approximate the value of quality in compress method right?

Comment: @M_ELsaghier: If "what [you] need" is to know exactly the size of the file that you will get for a given `compress()` call, that is not possible. It varies by image resolution and how well the image data compresses. Aiming for a particular file size is usually a pointless exercise, as there is no guarantee that you can reach it given *any* compression factor. Usually, we pick a compression factor that works fairly well for the type of images that we have (e.g., photos) and just use it.

Comment: how could I calculate that factor?

Comment: @M_ELsaghier: Try some values. Look at the images. See if the image quality is acceptable. Choose the value that gives you the smallest size while the quality is still acceptable.